# What does Malcolm mean in this joke about Tom Cruise's brush?

Tags: character, reference, the-thick-of-it

In **The Thick Of It**, when referring to a woman he finds insane, Malcolm Tucker says:

[image]

I've seen the Tom Cruise meme of him going nuts on Oprah, etc. But what is the "brush" reference about? Is this some British-specific humor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Daft as a brush**](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/as-daft-as-a-brush.html) is a colloquial British phrase meaning crazy or foolish.

I would take Malcolm's phrase as a joke to mean particularly mad as she is as daft as Tom Cruise's favorite brush.

Comment: So happy to be able to answer a Malcolm Tucker question.   As 'swearer in chief' he is one of my all-time favorite characters.

Comment: I didn't answer it because it's not in my purview ;)

Comment: @LaconicDroid ...... allow me to pop a jaunty little bonnet on your "purview" ....

Comment: @iandotkelly - are you british by chance? I may have a lot more of these questions...

Comment: @JacobIRR ... I am yes, but I live in the USA so I know how to translate :)